# The timeout period of 30000ms has been exceeded

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I'm using Quarkus Rest Client to call an endpoint which takes some time to give a response. After 30 seconds I get the following exception:

> The timeout period of 30000ms has been exceeded while executing GET < address > for server < server >

I've already tried tuning a bunch of properties - quarkus.rest-client.connect-timeout, quarkus.vertx.keep-alive-time, quarkus.http.test-timeout, quarkus.thread-pool.keep-alive-time - but I can't find the right one.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried `quarkus.rest-client.read-timeout`?